# Add fstl (program) to select application menu

Tags: software-installation

I am looking for a quick and easy way to view .stl files on ubuntu.

I have download various CAD programs but the only one I can get to work is FreeCAD which takes ages to load.

I stumbled upon fstl which is a fast loading .stl viewer which fits the bill. The only problem is that I can only open this program from the terminal.

My ultimate aim is to set ubuntu to open .stl files with fstl by default when I click on them. Right clicking on a .stl file and clicking "open with another application" gives me a list of applications which does not include fstl or even FreeCAD.

How do I add fstl to this menu? Did I not install it properly? I had to use synaptic package manager since it wasn't on the software store.

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10

Thank you

Richard

Answer (score 1):

Solved - I entered the following commands in the terminal:

"mimeopen -d examplefile.stl" (where examplefile is a .stl file on my desktop)

"4" (for "Other...")

"fstl"

This is the terminal output:

user@yourcomputer:~$ mimeopen -d examplefile.stl
Please choose a default application for files of type model/stl

```
1) Blender  (blender)
2) Cura (4.4.1)  (appimagekit_6ac323bcce2d099d10c57f4ce4a308a0-Cura)
3) Darktable  (darktable)
4) Other...
```

use application #4
use command: fstl